# Delegating events

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I've got a backbone view for an entire collection (a list of "clickable" categories). Can I delegate events on each item of the view so that I can find which category has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a post that might help.  Basically you use a data-* attribute in the item view to store and then retrieve the id of item clicked:

- [Backbone.js: Getting The Model For A Clicked Element](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/)

If you'd rather go directly to code, [here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/sh6Dv/14/) that's used in the post to demonstrate.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have no answer for your question (no, I think), but would like to share my approach: a general collection view component, which renders a collection using other view. It can be as simple as in the example below or more sophisticated (listening add/remove/reset events and react accordingly).

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function() {
        this.options.collection.each(function(model) {
            this.$el.append((new this.options.view({model : model})).el);
        }, this);
    }
})
```